# abrt - dump disappears within a few seconds

Tags: alma-linux, abrt

I have install abrt on AlmaLinux 8 and have triggered a crash:

```
~]$ sleep 100 &
[1] 2823
~]$ kill -s SIGSEGV 2823
```

I did see a folder momentarily in the `/var/spool/abrt` but it disappeared within a few seconds.

Also I can't seem to change the dump location. When I change the dump location by uncommenting and setting the configuration as `DumpLocation = /home/crash/abrt` and restarting `arbtd`, it fails to start.

Comment: selinux was the reason ```arbtd``` wouldn't start after changing dump location. Disabled selinux and now ```arbtd``` has started. I am still having issues with the dump files disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

`abrt` is configured to capture core dumps of applications installed with `rpm` or `yum`. Core dumps are not captured for applications that are not installed with `rpm` or `yum`.

You can change it to capture core dumps of all applications.

Please refer to the [following link](https://atl.kr/dokuwiki/doku.php/abrtd_application_core_dumps_delete).